# Is declaring a variable with an empty map, and then assigning a different object to it an efficient pattern?

Tags: oop, object, grails, groovy

We are developing a Grails project and I am am a Grails/Groovy novice and I am seeing a pattern where we define a variable as an empty map in the controller, and then in a service method also defining another empty map, and populating it with key/value pairs from the DB.

My contention is that this pattern is wasteful.  We are assigning an empty map to the controller variable, only to create another map in the service and then assigning the service map to the controller variable, thereby orphaning the empty map created in the controller, and releasing it for garbage collection.

A coworker contends that the data from the service map is ending up in the controller map, such that the original map created in the controller is being used and is therefore declaring it is not wasteful.

What is really happening?  Is that first controller map being created only to be garbage collected, or is it somehow being filled with the data in the service map?

Controller method:

```
getMap() {
    ....
    def output = [:]
    output = someService.getHashMap()
    ...
}
```

Service method:

```
getHashMap() {
    ...
    def output = [:]
    output = [key0: 'value0', key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2']
}
```

Comment: You are just cutting the original map reference lose for garbage collection. I would suggest just dropping the initial declaration and just use the service method return value or passing the map into the service method so it can be populated, if that's the desired behavior. Wasteful or not is a bit of an opinion-thing. The GC should be able to take care of it pretty quick but you are never using the original map, so my thought is yes, wasteful or at least annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no good reason to do something like this...

```
def output = [:]
output = [key0: 'value0', key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2']
```

Maybe this will help clarify what is going on.  The following is equivalent to the code above...

```
def output = new LinkedHashMap()
output = new LinkedHashMap()
output.put 'key0', 'value0'
output.put 'key1', 'value1'
output.put 'key2', 'value2'
```

Answer (score 2):

It is setting an object reference that is never used to a variable and then setting another reference of a different map instance (created inside the service probably). The garbage collector is going to remove the first empty map, it is not a big performance issue but is easily avoidable.
To add the contents of the map, you would need to use `putAll` or the left shift operator `<<`.

Comment: 'The garbage collector is going to remove the first empty map, it is not a big performance issue' while I agree, it is not a big preformance issue, but why write code that is never used? And with a large application that has trouble delivering content in a timely manner, why make the garbage collection clean up messes that should never have been made?

Comment: Yeah, for that reason I wrote that is easily avoidable, I agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally resent *(I know; it's a strong word)* re-assigning values to a variable. The following (ugly) pattern is one of the main roots of evil in your code:

```
def x = foo()
// do something with 'x'
...
x = bar()
// do something else with 'x'
```

This can easily make understanding the code very difficult and introduce bugs. You have to constantly keep an eye on `x` to make sure it contains the value it is supposed to! Really!
Just create another variable to hold the second value; there's absolutely **nothing** wrong with it --the days of 64KB of memory are long gone now.

```
def fooX = foo()
// do something with 'fooX'
...
def barX = bar()
// do something with 'barX'
```

This makes reading the code and understanding its behaviour, much easier.

Personally, when  I write code that needs to re-assign to a variable, I quickly realise that there's something wrong with the way I'm organising my code. I do it ONLY on extremely rare occasions.

Comment: me too, I agree with you, but I guess someone does not like criticism

Comment: Your example addresses a different situation than the one in the original question. Your example initialized a reference, uses the reference to do some things, then re assign the reference to some other object and then do something with that object. The original question is allocating an object that is never interacted with.